# How make a ember modal with an id?

Tags: ember.js, modal-dialog

Hi i try to make an simple ember app that's get info form a json file. App is located here:http://www.autoroben.nl/m/. Problem is i need the ember view return back an id (from the li element) which i need for handlebars. so i can pop up car info with the same jsonfile as the car list.

```
// MODAL
App.OpenModal = Ember.View.extend({
  click: function(evt) {
    var id = $(".lijst li").attr('id');
    alert(id)
    $('#modal').addClass('active');
  }
});
```

the template

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="index">
  <header class="bar bar-nav">
    <h1 class="title">AUTOROBEN</h1>
  </header>
  <div class="content">
    <ul class="table-view lijst">
    {{#each}}
    <li class="table-view-cell media" id="{{unbound ID}}">
        {{#view App.OpenModal}}
            <img src="/wp-content/uploads/{{unbound featured_image.attachment_meta.file}}" class="media-object pull-left" width="80">
            {{title}}
            <p>{{autoinfo.details.bouwjaar}} | {{autoinfo.details.kmstand}}</p>
        {{/view}}
      </li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </div>


   <div id="modal" class="modal">
      <header class="bar bar-nav">
        {{#view App.CloseModal}}
        <a class="icon icon-close pull-right nostyle" href="#"></a>
        {{/view}}
        <h1 class="title">{{title}}</h1>
      </header>

      <div class="content">
        <ul class="table-view">
          <li class="table-view-divider">DETAILS</li>
          <li class="table-view-cell">bouwjaar: {{autoinfo.details.bouwjaar}}</li>
          <li class="table-view-cell">kmstand: {{autoinfo.details.kmstand}}</li>
        </ul>     
     </div>
    </div> 
  </script>
```

json file:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return Ember.$.getJSON('http://www.autoroben.nl/wp-json/posts/?type=autos');
  }
});
```

Comment: Put the li inside the OpenModal view as tagName: 'li' . Then inside the click method you can use 'this.$().attr('id')'. You can also directly specify the id on the view as a property value.

Comment: I tried but how i use that id in index.html to read only json item witch is selected in list view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Views in ember js by default get the parent context as its own context. In your case its the context of an single item in the each helper. You can access the ID from the view using the following code.

```
App.OpenModal = Ember.View.extend({
  tagName: 'li',
  classNames: ['table-view-cell', 'media'],
  click: function(evt) {
    alert(this.get('context.ID'));
    $('#modal').addClass('active');
  }
});
```

[Here is a working bin.](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/racicu/1/edit)

Comment: thanx thats working, but how i get only the first array from the json file? tried this `{{#with this.[1]}} {{title}}
{{/with}}` but not working

Comment: Normally array indexes are refered in template as 'this.0.title'

Comment: Im not completely sure what your problem is. If you are trying to get your data to the close model, this is a way http://emberjs.jsbin.com/racicu/2/edit